# USUARIOS CON ROLES

Tags: laravel-5, users-roles

Alguien sabe algún vídeo tutorial para realizar eso? la creación de roles, y modificar las vistas?
ya que lo que necesito, que el menú (vertical) el botón 'Admin' y su respectiva pagina solo el administrador pueda acceder

Comment: Algo tan complejo hay poco gratis, esto lo puedes encontrar en cursos por ineternet, obviamente pagando, pero si no lo requeires asi tendras que investigar muchas cosas por separado

Comment: Si de echo eso estoy realizando :c, pero por si alguien necesita eso instalen VOYAGER, es ratuito y muy bueno, para mi mala suerte, mi profesor me dijo que yo no lo puedo ocupar.

Comment: Si quieres hacer esto de los roles, investiga lo que son las tablas pivot las relaciones has many has one y belongsto, tengo un sistema de roles así, deja ver de q manera lo puedo postear para q sea una respuesta y te ayude con tu problema

Comment: Gracias amigo!, de echo estoy comenzando a ocupar LaraTrust pero aun no entiendo mucho como ocuparlo

Comment: Mira encontre este videotutorial de raul palacion que es bueno explicando y esta parte te interesara
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pP2cds7tu-8